# Assign Server policy using command line in newrelic

Tags: newrelic

Is there a Command / API in newrelic that can be used to assign a server policy to a server ? I'm trying to write a bootstrap script which would run every time I provision a new server, and I don't fancy going to the newrelic dashboard everytime to change the policy for that server.

I tried going through this REST Api [doc](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/alert-policies/rest-api-alert-policies) but couldn't find anything that serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the alert entity API. There is an add capability within that API tree that lets you add an entity (a server or an APM agent etc.) to an existing alert condition.

Add an entity to a condition
To add an entity to a condition, include these items in the API call:

1. Your REST API key or Admin user's API key
   The entity_id This is the entity (alert target) to be monitored. It is the numeric ID for the Application, Browser, Server, Plugin, Key transaction, or Mobile application.
2. The condition_id (available from API Explorer:  Alerts Conditions > GET > List)
3. The entity_type which must be one of the following (not Synthetics at this time):
   BrowserApplication
   Application
   MobileApplication
   Server
   KeyTransaction
   Plugin
4. API Explorer:  Alerts Entity Conditions > PUT > Add

   ```
   curl -X PUT 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/alerts_entity_conditions/{entity_id}.json' \
    -H 'X-Api-Key:{api_key}' -i \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -G -d 'entity_type={entity_type}&condition_id={condition_id}'
   ```

Comment: Could you please provide a link to the documentation ?

Comment: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/alerts/new-relic-alerts/rest-api-alerts/rest-api-calls-new-relic-alerts

Comment: ah, so what I understand from this is that it allows me to add / remove my server from an alert condition, however I want to change the 'policy' itself, not the alert condition. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Why do you want to change the policy itself? The condition is what has the servers in it that will adhere to the policy.

Comment: In my case I'm provisioning test servers to do some experiments. I need data in newrelic, but I don't want the whole dev team to be alerted, so my notification channels are different. The default server policy is what usually is provisioned for all servers, so I created a test server policy, I'm just looking for a programmatic way to assign that policy to any new test server that I provision.

Comment: You don't assign policies to servers you assign servers to policies,. The original API call I gave you will help you do that. If you have the server policy already created, use the add alert condition PUT API to add in new servers that will be part of the policy.